# getopt only reads in only the first command

Tags: c, getopt

I have a question regarding the behavior of my `getopt` function.
My code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int opt;

     while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "gi:o:ctp")) != -1) {
         switch(opt) {
            case 'i':
                   printf("entered i\n" );
                   break;

            case 'o':
                   printf("entered o\n" );
                   break;
         }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

However when I entered `./run -i in -o out`, it only prints out `entered i` and stops.
Could anyone help me out?

Comment: I'm not seeing the behavior even after the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass another argument to `-i` and `-o` because a colon follows those letters in the `optstring`.

Like this:

```
./run -i in -o out
```

Alternatively, you could make the arguments' arguments optional by adding additional colons in the `optstring`:

```
     while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "gi::o::ctp")) != -1) {
```

Comment: I tried, also added another colon but it's still not working...

Comment: @rodan You'll need to share all of your code for more help. I can't tell what this is trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for you advice! I have edited a bit of the code above, basically I'm just trying out the getopt function

Comment: @rodan I can't reproduce this. It prints out `entered i` `entered o` when I run it as `./a.out -i in -o out`.

Comment: I got i! Thank you so much!